# how to delete/remove calico cni from my kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, flannel, calico

I have installed my kubernetes cluster(1master, 3worker)in the digital ocean.
The problem is I installed both flannel and calico in this cluster.
I want to remove the calico completely from my cluster or is it ok to have multiple CNI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use following two commands to remove calico from your node:

```
kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml
kubectl delete -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml
```

Comment: How did you add calico to the cluster or it came by default with cluster deployment?

Comment: do we need to replace v3.3 in the URL with our installed version?

Comment: @PrafullLadha-: I tried your Kubectl delete commands but I am not able to delete calicoctl . The command and calico pods are still up. My calico version is: Client Version:    v3.19.1
Git commit:        6fc0db96

Answer (score -1):

You should add these

https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/rbac-kdd.yaml

and

https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.3/getting-started/kubernetes/installation/hosted/kubernetes-datastore/calico-networking/1.7/calico.yaml

to your ansible playbook file state as "absent" then when you run ansible playbook file i.e as below.

```
- name: Delete Calico (rbac-kdd.yaml) from cluster
  kubernetes:
    api_endpoint: 123.45.67.89
    insecure: true
    file_reference: /path/to/rbac-kdd.yaml
    state: absent

- name: Delete Calico (calico.yaml) from cluster
  kubernetes:
    api_endpoint: 123.45.67.89
    insecure: true
    file_reference: /path/to/calico.yaml
    state: absent
```

Please check your ansible playbook file for cluster installation and change/modify values according your needs.

For more details kubernetes with ansible you can see this:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/kubernetes_module.html

I hope it will be helpful for you

Comment: Did I miss where the question indicates they use Ansible?

Comment: @CashIsClay that's right, you miss the fact that this question is edited in Dec 19 2019, and my answer was Dec 4 2018.

Comment: @coolinuxoid the revision of the edit only shows that  `or is it ok to have multiple CNI?` was added.. no mention of Ansible

Comment: @Coffeeholic not sure what you are trying to achieve but I am sure that question was with Ansible related. I remember this very well

Answer (score -3):

PLease change the security group, If its AWS
If its s VM, Expose the port

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32826921)

Comment: This answer is not useful.