# How to delete calicoctl and iptables (created by calico installation) from my k3s

Tags: kubernetes, calico, calicoctl

I have a K3s setup with calico pods [`calico-node-` & `calico-kube-controllers-`] running. On uninstalling K3s, calico pods get deleted but I see that `calicoctl` and `iptables -S` commands still running and shows data.

I want to delete calico (including *calicoctl* and *Iptables* created by calico) completely. Which commands will help me to do so ?

**K3s uninstalltion command:** `/usr/local/bin/k3s-uninstall.sh` deletes all k3s pods including calico, but `calicoctl` and `iptables -S` still works.

**PS:** I already tried few things -

1. Command `kubectl delete -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws/amazon-vpc-cni-k8s/release-1.5/config/v1.5/calico.yaml` deletes the `calico-node-` but *`calico-kube-controller`* , *`calicoctl`* and *`iptables -S`* are still present
2. `Kubectl delete` commands in [this que](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53610641/how-to-delete-remove-calico-cni-from-my-kubernetes-cluster/53610810#53610810) also not working for me, after executing these two commands still *`calicoctl`* and *`iptables -S`* are present

Comment: Yes? Those are separate tools which you might have already had installed so removing them is probably out of scope for the uninstaller or it could damage systems. `iptables` especially is almost always preinstalled and critical to system functioning.

Comment: @coderanger:- 1. Iptables command is already present but Iptables of calico created only after calico installation . 2. Isn't there way to uninstall calicoctl and Iptables-created-by-calico manually by some kubectl command or script ? I have edited the title for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

**Deleting calico-Iptables:**

Use [calico-policy](https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-calico-policy.sh) and add below lines at the end of script:

```
echo "Flush remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -F

echo "Delete remaining calico iptables"
iptables-save | grep -i cali | iptables -X
```

This will delete all calico iptables when you check with `iptables -S`

**Note:** Run this script only after uninstalling K3S.

**Deleting calicoctl:**

Simply run `sudo rm $(which calicoctl)` command, it will find and delete the calicoctl.

Answer (score 0):

Calico does not provide any automatic uninstallers that I am aware of. You'll have to handle this yourself.

Comment: @coderanger-:: I can see some disabling link on there GitHub https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/blob/master/hack/remove-calico-policy/remove-policy.md . There is iptables-remover-ds.yaml & remove-calico-policy.sh scripts , can't this help ? 
 https://github.com/projectcalico/calico/tree/master/hack/remove-calico-policy

Comment: That doesn't look at all related, you can read the scripts and see exactly what they do.

Comment: Looks like links are broken . Have they removed the script now ?